# Finite product of complex functions

Tags: complex-numbers

Reading a Russian book "Lectures on Mathematical Analysis" by Arkhipov, Sadovnichy and Chubarikov, in the section "Integral Sums Method" I encountered an equality, which I cannot prove. Here it is:
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{n}|(\alpha-e^{ix_k})\cdot(\alpha-e^{-ix_k})|=|\alpha^{2n}-1|, x_k={\pi k\over n}
$$
Could somebody, please, explain, how to prove this. I think it has something to do with root of unity.

Comment: Look at the roots of the polynomial $z^{2n}-1$

Comment: I see now. It's simple, but complex numbers is my weak part so far, I studied them long time ago. I hope to read again a book on complex analysis by Privalov in years to come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the roots of $f(x)=x^{2n}-1$. What is $f(\alpha)$?

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to help.

Comment: I've noticed, however, that left hand side has a double root -1, while right hand side has roots 1 and -1 instead, I think that there's mistake in the book, and right hand side should contain multiplier 
$$
{|\alpha+1|\over |\alpha-1|}
$$
Although the final answer to the problem in the book remains correct.

Comment: Yes, you are correct indeed.